# Is there any use of earthing without fuse?

Tags: electricity

Can just an earthing connection (without fuse) possibly prevent an electric shock if the live wire of an electronic device touches the bare metal body,

Answer (score 0):

The problem would be that you now have the live wire connected to the earth and a very large current would flow through the wires and obviously less through you.  That very large current through the live wire would heat the wire up which could cause a fire.

So the fuse is not just there to protect you it is also there to protect the wiring from excessively large currents.